# WIX Installer for Test/Live Environment

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have to create a set up file for a client app for LIVE/QA/UAT environments and the only difference between them is the app.config file. Can you please suggest an easy way to accomplish it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good approach is modifying a template app.config based on user input:

- configure your app.config file to use installer properties: http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_xmlfile.htm
- create some custom dialogs which retrieve the element information from the user and save them in your custom properties

Answer (score 2):

If you need to update just certain value in app.config based on user input, then the solution outlined by @Cosmin would work best. There are a couple of other options depending on your requirements:

- in case you can define the app.config differences at buildtime, and if it's fine to have 3 different MSI packages (one per environment), it's better to author 3 components holding the app.config for each environment wrapped in the preprocessor logic. As a result, you'll end up with an MSI package for a specific environment depending on how you build
- in case the choice depends on a certain user input, you can still author 3 different components with mutual exclusive conditions, and this conditions will depend on the user input

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this before by using something along the lines of this in my main wxs file:

```
<?include $(sys.CURRENTDIR)Properties$(var.Configuration).wxi?>
```

(It points to e.g. C:\MyProjectDir\PropertiesDebug.wxi, C:\MyProjectDir\PropertiesUAT.wxi, etc. depending on the active solution configuration).

However, I now prefer using the new Microsoft method of having the web.config and app.config transforms for each platform, because it can help to shift the burden of maintaining these settings onto the developers who create them as they go, rather than just leaving it all to the guy that writes the installer app at the end.

The app.config transforms are not built into VS2010, but there is an add-in available:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5

The web.config transforms are built in already:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2009/05/04/web-deployment-web-config-transformation.aspx